# Write the docker-compose.yaml to avoid defining the port to the domain ip to access to the shinyapp

Tags: docker-compose, yaml, dockerfile, shinyapps

I am new to using the docker compose command and creating the yaml file.

I have the following problem. I have a shinyapp that dialogs directly with a postgres database with the postgis extension.

When I go to develop the app in the host provider, i can acess to the shinyapp by specifying the ip and port such as

10.10.10.10:80

is there any way that enable me to go to the IP adress that automatically sends me to the IP:port in which the application is running.

This is the dockerfile I use to build my shinyapp image

```
FROM rocker/verse:4.2.0
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl gdal-bin git-core imagemagick libcurl4-openssl-dev libfontconfig1-dev libgdal-dev libgeos-dev libgeos++-dev libgit2-dev libicu-dev libjq-dev libpng-dev libpq-dev libproj-dev libprotobuf-dev libsasl2-dev libssl-dev libudunits2-dev libv8-dev libxml2-dev make pandoc pandoc-citeproc protobuf-compiler libprotoc-dev zlib1g-dev && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN echo "options(repos = c(CRAN = 'https://cran.rstudio.com/'), download.file.method = 'libcurl', Ncpus = 4)" >> /usr/local/lib/R/etc/Rprofile.site
RUN R -e 'install.packages("remotes")'
RUN Rscript -e 'remotes::install_version("htmltools",upgrade="never", version = "0.5.2")'
RUN Rscript -e 'remotes::install_version("stringr",upgrade="never", version = "1.4.1")'
RUN Rscript -e 'remotes::install_version("processx",upgrade="never", version = "3.7.0")'
RUN Rscript -e 'remotes::install_version("rmarkdown",upgrade="never", version = "2.15")'
RUN Rscript -e 'remotes::install_version("ggplot2",upgrade="never", version = "3.3.6")'
RUN Rscript -e 'remotes::install_version("DBI",upgrade="never", version = "1.1.3")'
RUN Rscript -e 'remotes::install_version("shiny",upgrade="never", version = "1.7.2")'
RUN Rscript -e 'remotes::install_version("sp",upgrade="never", version = "1.5-0")'
RUN Rscript -e 'remotes::install_version("sf",upgrade="never", version = "1.0-8")'
RUN Rscript -e 'remotes::install_version("raster",upgrade="never", version = "3.5-21")'
RUN Rscript -e 'remotes::install_version("plotly",upgrade="never", version = "4.10.0")'
RUN Rscript -e 'remotes::install_version("viridis",upgrade="never", version = "0.6.2")'
RUN Rscript -e 'remotes::install_version("leaflet",upgrade="never", version = "2.1.1")'
RUN Rscript -e 'remotes::install_version("DT",upgrade="never", version = "0.23")'
RUN Rscript -e 'remotes::install_version("rgdal",upgrade="never", version = "1.5-32")'
RUN Rscript -e 'remotes::install_version("rgeos",upgrade="never", version = "0.5-9")'
RUN Rscript -e 'remotes::install_version("xgboost",upgrade="never", version = "1.6.0.1")'
RUN Rscript -e 'remotes::install_version("mapview",upgrade="never", version = "2.11.0")'
RUN Rscript -e 'remotes::install_version("tidyverse",upgrade="never", version = "1.3.2")'
RUN Rscript -e 'remotes::install_version("tidymodels",upgrade="never", version = "0.2.0")'
RUN Rscript -e 'remotes::install_version("SpatialPosition",upgrade="never", version = "2.1.1")'
RUN Rscript -e 'remotes::install_version("rpostgis",upgrade="never", version = "1.4.3")'
RUN Rscript -e 'remotes::install_version("writexl",upgrade="never", version = "1.4.0")'
RUN Rscript -e 'remotes::install_version("weathermetrics",upgrade="never", version = "1.2.2")'
RUN Rscript -e 'remotes::install_version("SPEI",upgrade="never", version = "1.7")'
RUN Rscript -e 'remotes::install_version("spdplyr",upgrade="never", version = "0.4.0")'
RUN Rscript -e 'remotes::install_version("sever",upgrade="never", version = "0.0.7")'
RUN Rscript -e 'remotes::install_version("rtsdata",upgrade="never", version = "0.1.3")'
RUN Rscript -e 'remotes::install_version("RPostgres",upgrade="never", version = "1.4.4")'
RUN Rscript -e 'remotes::install_version("RMySQL",upgrade="never", version = "0.10.23")'
RUN Rscript -e 'remotes::install_version("randomForest",upgrade="never", version = "4.7-1.1")'
RUN mkdir /build_zone
ADD . /build_zone
WORKDIR /build_zone
RUN R -e 'options(warn = 2);remotes::install_local(upgrade="never")'
EXPOSE 80
CMD R -e "options('shiny.port'=80,shiny.host='0.0.0.0');webapp4::run_app()"
```

And this is my docker-compose.yaml che ho creato

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: kartoza/postgis:14-3.2
    volumes: 
      - ./mypostgres-dump/dumpfile.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_tables.sql
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=XXX
      - POSTGRES_USER=XXXX
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=XXXX
      - POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_EXTENSIONS=postgis, postgis_raster
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: always
    networks:
      - skynet
  shiny:
    build: ./webapp
    restart: always
    container_name: shiny
    depends_on:
      - "db"
    expose:
      - "80"
    networks:
      - skynet
networks:
  skynet:
```

Comment: I’m not entirely sure what your setup Is, but I think you are attempting to access the container from the host machine. What happens when you visit `http://localhost` in your browser? (That implies port 80.) Also, are you sure nothing else is using port 80? Typically, you would bind to a much higher port like 8080 to ensure no other processes is going to interfere with your port.

Comment: I would like to make it so that when one searches for the following ip 10.10.10.10 goes directly to the 10.10.10.10:80 without specify the port.